# How do I get my Node/Socket.io chat to communicate when it's on a domain?

Tags: javascript, deployment, node.js, socket.io

I have successfully written a very simple real-time chat out of Node JS and Socket.io. It also uses Express, Jade and Stylus - which I want to develop further.

The current code for this is here (this works locally): https://github.com/littlejim84/basic_node_socket

This is all running fine and works as expected on my local machine. Running the Node app and going to http://localhost:9000/ makes the thing work as expected. But when I put it up on my remote server, the socket wasn't connecting. I had setup Ngnix to server my Node app, something like this:

```
upstream basic_node_socket { 
    server 127.0.0.1:9000; 
} 

server { 
    listen   80; 
    server_name  example.com; 

    location /basic_node_socket { 
        root /var/www/example.com/basic_node_socket; 

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true; 

        proxy_pass http://basic_node_socket/; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    } 
}
```

With this I could go to the web address and it would server up my Node app, as expected, but the socket just won't connect. I'm presuming it's because on the client side now, I am listening to port 9000, which maybe has no relevance anymore now it's being served this way?

In my client side script I have this (which does work locally):

```
socket = new io.Socket(null, {port: 9000});
```

I'm not an expert at Node, I'm trying to wrap my head around it. Can anyone help me get this to work as expected on my remote server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I have seen this link which seems to detail my problem: http://community.webfaction.com/questions/3448/using-websockets-with-a-nodejs-custom-app

...this is fine and I understand I will probably need a dedicated IP so I can run Node purely on port 80 and have one of my domain names point to that IP (or I could use something like Nodestar). But I want to keep things on my own VPS. This seems good, as long as I have one Node app running. But what if I want two, or three Node JS apps running on that new dedicated IP address? That's the bit I don't understand. I've seen various vhost type setups for Node JS, but I'm not really sure how best to implement that cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem and haven't dealt with this first hand, but my understanding is that you cannot proxy websockets with nginx. That's probably why you are having troubles with websockets but not other requests.

Try using:
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

I've also heard that lighttpd works with websockets.

Comment: Tauren is correct, nginx can't proxy websockets, but there are patches to do with this if you REALLY want to use websockets and nginx, see here: http://www.stephendiehl.com/?p=309

Comment: @addisonj @Tauren Could I not follow this blog article? Would this help? http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets

Comment: @littlejim84 I'm not using nginx so I don't know for sure, but it looks like that could work. Is there a problem using a node-only solution like node-http-proxy? You would have it run on port 80 and have your other node apps run on various unprivileged ports. This will allow you to have multiple node apps running on the same server. If you want this to be a public facing solution, you will probably want a dedicated IP number, but you shouldn't need more than one. You can even have separate domain names hosted on the same server with only one IP. See: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-intro

Answer (score 0):

As to the error you had with Socket.IO, if you are fronting the app on port 9000 with nginx on port 80, you will need to tell the client side to use port 80 NOT port 9000.

You can look at node-http-proxy with a simple proxyTable lookup map. To map port 80 to multiple sites.

You could also look at nodester.com, it will provide you with a node.js hosting platform.

Answer (score -1):

You could run a single http server and route the request based on the domain or other information in the request. Using this method you could serve up entirely different sites for different domains that are using the same IP address on the same server. There's probably [a module or two](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#web-frameworks-routers) available to help you with this. As for multiple socket.io instances, you can start http servers on different ports and use them to run as many socket.io instances you want on the same machine.